# Can we insert in multiple tables using bigtable

Tags: python, google-cloud-bigtable

I have a use case where I have to write the events data in multiple tables using bigtable in python. Is it possible in bigtable or we can't do that in bigtable .
When I try to write the data in multiple table in the same code then this issue occurs.
google.cloud.bigtable.table.TableMismatchError:

Please confirm whether we can do it using bigtable or not.

Answer (score 0):

Bigtable doesn't have support for writing to multiple tables, so you'd need to get a connection for each table and then group the writes by table. You could do something like this:

```
table1 = instance.table(table_id1)
table2 = instance.table(table_id2)

timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
column_family_id = "stats_summary"

rows1 = [table.direct_row("tablet#a0b81f74#20190501"),
        table.direct_row("tablet#a0b81f74#20190502")]

rows1[0].set_cell(...)
rows1[0].set_cell(...)
rows1[1].set_cell(...)
rows1[1].set_cell(...)

rows2 = [table.direct_row("tablet#20190501#a0b81f74"),
        table.direct_row("tablet#20190502#a0b81f74")]

rows2[0].set_cell(...)
rows2[0].set_cell(...)
rows2[1].set_cell(...)
rows2[1].set_cell(...)

response1 = table1.mutate_rows(rows)
response2 = table2.mutate_rows(rows)
```

There are more examples of how to perform various [writes in the Bigtable documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/writing-data), so once you create your other Bigtbale table connections, then you can just follow those examples.